# How to create a java client to connect to Websphere server using SOAP protocol

Tags: web-services, authentication, jakarta-ee, soap, websphere

I am using a software called Splunk, which is supposed to connect to a websphere server. This is not working.

To rule out any problems with my Websphere server, I want to write a Java program like this:

**Connect to the websphere server by passing in**:

Host name/IP

Port port ('SOAP_CONNECTOR_ADDRESS=18024' specified in websphere console)

Username + password for authentication

I have successfully tested the basic program:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    final String host = "abd-def-ghi";
    final int portNumber = 81;
    System.out.println("Creating socket to '" + host + "' on port " + portNumber);

    while (true) {
        Socket socket = new Socket(host, portNumber);
        if(socket.getInetAddress().isReachable(60)) {
            System.out.println("Still connected");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Disconnected");
            socket.close();
            break;
        }
    }       
}
```

}

How do I pass in the username + password and connect to the SOAP connector port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to do this test without writing any code, using wsadmin with -conntype SOAP option.

Comment: Thankyou! Can you please give me a link to a tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: Have a look at this link: 

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_commandline.html

Comment: from (was_home)/profiles/(profile_dir)/bin, you probably want to run this one:  

wsadmin.sh/bat -conntype SOAP [-host host_name] [-port port_number] [-user userid] [-password password]

if you're connecting to the same profile it usually just works, but there are some files in (profile_dir)/properties, wsadmin.properites and ssl.client.props, that affect wsadmin. 

To find the port, you can look at (profile_dir)/logs/AboutThisProfile.txt, that shows the ports used when it was created, although things might have changed since then.

Comment: Thankyou! Much appreciated.